# How to get a text value from a sub string by index in C#

Tags: c#, listview, indexing, subitem

I have a `listview1` with information about students that can change repeatedly, as well for the Student Names (`Column1`) and the Students task `Column2`.

I have a `textBox1` where you can type the name a possible student in `Column1`.
That name will be transfered into a `string` named `searchstr`.

As soon as the command hits, an item in `Column1` will be checked for it's existence (and if it equals the `searchstr`).

if so, the Name of that student has an Index number which I receive via the commandline `var index = listview.Items.IndexOf(Name);`

Now with that Index number I try to receive the text value of that students task (the Subitem from `Column2`) and set it in a string. Is this possible?

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listview1.Items)
 {
   if (item.SubItems[0].Text == searchstr)
     {
       var Name = listview1.FindItemWithText(searchstr);

       if (Name != null)
        {
          var index = listview.Items.IndexOf(Name);
        }
     }

 }
```

Comment: `string task=listview.Items[index].SubItems[1].Text`? I'm not sure I understand your question...

Comment: In this case does the index actually matter? When a string is typed into the search just rerun your query, filtering by the search string. A sub-set will be returned and you will only be working with the returned values. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @StephenBrickner You actually solved it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @RobertWesterveld, no problem, glad it helped